# How would i be able to read this file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, iostream

So I'm trying to read in this file but I'm having trouble as i have to read them into an array.

```
CONVERT  00000000
NOT      00000000
AND      00001111  11110000
OR       00001111  11110000
CONVERT  11111111
IR       11111111  00000000
NOT      11001100
LSHIFT   11001101  3
CONVERT  01011101
AND      10111011  00111000
LSHIFT   11001101  8
OR       10000001  10011001
CONVURT  10101010
LSHIFT   11111111  1
```

So I'm suppose to read in the commands which i created an enum list for and basically check to see which ones are real commands if not display a wrong message. but I'm having trouble just reading in the file especially with the binary numbers? what would be the best way to gather the info in this folder? The only error ive been given is 11db but im sure that was just a minor error it  went away.

[Code]
https://pastebin.com/6gaSnvEr

Comment: Have you try with some implementation ? have you a code ?

Comment: Read each line into a string. Put each string into a `stringstream` and then attempt to read 3 strings from the stringstream. Checking that each of the reads succeed. If only 2 succeed, then you know there is no third value. You could create a simple `struct` with three strings, e.g. `struct operation { std::string command {}, arg1 {}, arg2 {}; };` and create a `std::vector` of those.

Comment: I recommend reading in the binary digits as a string.

Comment: You could put all the valid command names into a `std::vector` or `std::set`.  Search the container for the input ext.  If the input text is not found, then you have an invalid command.

Comment: Put the code, your [mcve], in the question. Don't link to an external site. Not everyone can read that and external sites may disappear and then the question is useless for others coming here to get help for a similar thing. Note that you should remove unused variables and functions from your minimal example. There's no need to litter the example with things that are unused. It only makes it harder to help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can read it line by line andy split the lines by spaces `' '`.

So you will get each part as a string you can parse or check it.

Please also share your code and errors you face so you can have better help.